# Smooth Scroll to Anchor not working

Tags: jquery, joomla-3.4

I am trying to implement a smooth scroll when the user clicks on a link to an anchor in my Joomla site. The anchor link works fine, but the user is brought to the anchor instantly. I don't believe the javascript is working correctly, but I do not get any sort of error in my console on Google Chrome.

This is the exact working javascript I am using: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNBMXZ

It works fine there, but when I try to put it in my Joomla site, it does not. I currently have the script at the end of the article with the anchor, but I also tried to load it in a file in the header.

Like I said, I do not see any sort of errors, so I'm not sure where to go from here.

EDIT:
Here is the output of console.log(target) when the anchor link is clicked.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you may not have wrapped document ready around your code, so try copying and pasting the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {

        var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

        if( target.length ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }   
    });  
});
```

### The problem

The problem being is that the child span element for your menu item has an `onclick` function, like so:

```
<a href="#test">
    <span onclick="window.document.location.href="#test">test</span>
</a>
```

So the standard `href="#test"` is not triggered.

I don't know how your template works, but somehow, you need to remove the following from the span element:

```
onclick="window.document.location.href="#test"
```

Comment: No change when implementing document ready. That's actually something I had tried.

Comment: start using `console.log()` to see if anything is returning null

Comment: I've never used console log before. This does not seem to be working for me:jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(e) {
console.log (
        var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );

        if( target.length ) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
);
    });  
});

Comment: I added a console.log after my click function and when I click my anchor link, I see my console log. So it does appear that it is getting that far.

Comment: You only need to console log the variable like so: `console.log (target);`

Comment: If I change templates, my script works fine. It is obviously conflicting with something else. Any easy way to find out?

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link to your site?

Comment: I created a test link on a site that is using the same template. You can test it by clicking the test menu link: http://chrisabel.net/ist666/

Comment: I don't mean to be a pest, but did you have a chance to look at the site. Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @Intrepid - See my update

Comment: @Intrepid - No problem. If this solved the issue, please click the "tick" icon next to the answer to mark it as "solved"